# Automatic website login opening Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to open a tab from a Chrome extension immediately after Chrome gets opened? My school has an access point which you have to sign in to every time you open up your computer to use the internet, and I would like to make an extension that automatically logs me in, but I cannot figure out how to make the script run as soon as I open Chrome.

**EDIT**: The login page is not the page that is opened when I open the browser: I've got to manually go to a certain site to make the system prompt me to log in, otherwise it will just tell me I'm not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Preparation

What you need to do here is to:

1. Create a basic "empty" extension with the required `manifest.json` file.
2. Declare the [`"background"` field](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), which will run a `backgrond.js` script to open the login page when Chrome is opened, using the [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs). You'll need then to add a permission for that.
3. Declare the [`"content_scripts"` field](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in your manifest, and set a `contnet.js` script to match the login URL that gets opened and allows you to log in.
4. The script (`content.js`), which will be executed in the created tab, will contain the code to automatically fill the fields with username and password and click the log-in button.

### Implementation

1. Create a basic extension, which will contain three files:

   - `manifest.json`: the extension's manifest
   - `background.js`: the extension's background script
   - `content.js`: your content script
2. Write the essential fields in your manifest, like: version, name, background etc. Then add the `"content_scripts"` field to declare your script. Your `manifest.json` should then look like this:

   ```
   {
       "manifest_version": 2,

       "name": "Some name",
       "version": "0",

       "permissions": [
           "tabs"
       ],

       "background": {
           "scripts": ["background.js"]
       },

       "content_scripts": {
           {
               "matches": ["http://your-login-page-url..."],
               "js": "/content.js"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your `background.js` script you'll open a tab right when the extension is started (which is also when Chrome gets opened), like this:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://your-login-page-url..."});
   // this URL ---------------^^ should be the same as the one that matches the content script in the manifest.json
   ```

   Change the URL with the real one and check that the opened tab is the right one.
4. Now, in your `content.js` script, which will be loaded into the tab that has just been created, you'll get the right fields and fill them up, then click the login button.

   For example, if the login page looks something like this:

   ```html
   ...
       <span>User:</span><input id="username" type="text"/>
       <span>Password:</span><input id="password" type="password"/>
       <button id="login-btn">Log in</button>
   ...
   ```

   Then in your `content.js` script you'll do:

   ```
   document.getElementById('username').value = 'yourusername';
   document.getElementById('password').value = 'yourpassword';
   document.getElementById('login-btn').click();
   ```

   Obviously you'll have to replace `yourusername` and `yourpassowrd` with the real credentials.

That's all, pretty easy: just a tab creation and a content script injected inside it. This extension will now log-in for you right when you open Chrome!

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but that doesn't quite answer my question. I know how to implement the code, I just want to know how to make the extension "turn on" when I first open chrome to direct me to a website that will activate the sign in process.

Comment: It is probably doable to open the site in an iframe in the background page itself, since you're going with the `background` permission route it would make more sense.

Comment: @Xan I assumed the user actually wanted to see the login page after "hitting" the login button. I'm usually used to look at the stats that get shown after the login succeeds (like some time or band limits' info etc).

Comment: Also, a bit of an error there. The background script for the extension will execute when Chrome is opened **without** `background` permission. Background permission is needed to start even _earlier_, at logon.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension with a [Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages). The background page would just need to [open a new tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) at the right url for the login page. Your manifest would specify one script for the background page

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

and that script would just contain this one line of JavaScript:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'the login page url' });
```

This works because background pages are loaded and persisted in memory when the browser starts. Therefore the js file is executed just once when you open the browser. The background page can be reloaded when the extension is updated, but since this will be a private extension you don't have to worry about that and it only makes development easier.